# Session Value becomes null on Page refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I am trying to save the value in a session and then on page refresh, I am trying to use that value. But every time, it goes inside the loop .

I am using `HttpContext.Current.Session` because my class is inheriting from `HTMLTable`.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"] == null)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"] = "2";
}  
string a = HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"].ToString(); //I get 2, WORKS HERE
```

Comment: Check your HTTP traffic (e.g. using Chrome console) and ensure the ASP.NET_SessionId cookie is being presented and its value is not changing.  This will help isolate the problem, e.g. perhaps your session cookie is marked secure but you are not using https.

Comment: Is there any other way except Session to do this thing ?

Comment: why does it go inside a loop? can you share the rest of the code? are you clearing the session anywhere?

Comment: Depends what "this thing" refers to.  If you are asking in general how to persist state between page requests, you could also use cookies, querystring, hidden form variables, or a database.

Comment: @Sushil No, I am not clearing anything. Not using it anywhere. I have updated the question, can you have a look ?

Comment: what is this loop you're talking about?

Comment: Sorry not a loop, just a condition. (If condition)

Comment: Where is this code? Is it on your page?

Comment: In a cs file. That cs file inherits 'HTMLTable'

Comment: it is difficult to say anything without the whole code. this code here should work fine.

Comment: Did you initialized your session variable some were on .CS page with null?

Comment: try to use concept of `IsPostBack`. i hope you are familiar with it

Comment: simply use `Session["Id"]`